# Disable browser back button for specific component when direct to another site

Tags: angular

I want to disable browser back button when we are redirecting to one site to another.

I'm using Angular v10. I have two different sites suppose `site.com` and `anothersite.com`.I am using below code in component of `site.com` site

Example: Page 1

```
private unsubscriber: Subject < void > = new Subject < void > ();

ngOnInit(): void {
    history.pushState(null, '');
    fromEvent(window, 'popstate')
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscriber))
        .subscribe((_) => {
            history.pushState(null, '');
        });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscriber.next();
    this.unsubscriber.complete();
}
```

First Redirecting to Page1 -> Page2-> Page3 -> Redirecting to  `anothersite.com`

There is one link on anothersite to go back, click on this link will land to Page1 of `site.com` where all my code exits.

Now when I click on browser back window popstate and  `history.pushState(null, '')` not working.

How we can disable back button when URL completely change ?